OpenModelica water hammer model - result not what I am expecting
I'm trying to learn how to use OpenModelica.
For a while, I have been trying to make a simple model to simulate the water hammer effect caused by a valve suddenly closing in a system of dynamic pipes, but I keep running into problems.
screenshot of OM model
I first made the model using CompressibleLiquids.LinearWater_pT_Ambient, but the pressure in the pipe right after the valve would go down to around -8000Pa and the simulation would stop.
I have then tried using StandardWater, the simulation finishes but the result is not quite what I expected. After the valve is closed I expected the pressure in the pipes before the valve to eventually equal the pressure of the inlet boundary(4bar), but it stays at 1 bar, and the pressure increase is about double of what I expected, with a lot more instability.
After recreating a similar system in a different 1d simulation software the result there agrees with what I expected to see.
Expected graph of pressure in pipe 4
I suspect the issue is something to do with the fluid I am using but not too sure what to do about it, any help or advice is appreciated.
Here is my model.
model WaterHammer
  Modelica.Fluid.System system1(T_ambient = 301.15, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, use_eps_Re = true) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-90, 90}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Inlet(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1, p = 399999.9999999999) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-90, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, allowFlowReversal = true, diameter = 3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 1000, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 2, p_a_start = 1e5, p_b_start = 1e5, redeclare model FlowModel = Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.FlowModels.DetailedPipeFlow, roughness = 0) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-58, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure pressure1(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-48, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure pressure2(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-10, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, allowFlowReversal = true, diameter = 3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 1000, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 2, p_a_start = 1e5, p_b_start = 1e5, roughness = 0) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-20, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, allowFlowReversal = true, diameter = 3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 1000, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 2, p_a_start = 1e5, p_b_start = 1e5, roughness = 0) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {20, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure pressure3(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {30, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.Pressure pressure4(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {60, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, allowFlowReversal = true, diameter = 3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 1000, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 2, p_a_start = 1e5, p_b_start = 1e5, roughness = 0) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {50, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Outlet(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1, p = 99999.99999999999) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-10, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear valveLinear(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, dp_nominal = 5e4, m_flow_nominal = 30000)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {60, 0}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp ramp(height = -1, duration = 0.1, offset = 1, startTime = 299.9)  annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {-36, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}})));
Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe41(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, allowFlowReversal = true, diameter = 3, energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, height_ab = 0, length = 1000, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial, nNodes = 2, p_a_start = 1e5, p_b_start = 1e5, roughness = 0) annotation(
    Placement(transformation(origin = {50, -50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
equation
  connect(Inlet.ports[1], pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-80, 50}, {-68, 50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe2.port_b, pressure2.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-10, 50}, {-10, 70}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe2.port_b, pipe3.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-10, 50}, {10, 50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe3.port_b, pipe4.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{30, 50}, {40, 50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, pressure1.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-48, 50}, {-48, 70}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, pipe2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-48, 50}, {-30, 50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe3.port_b, pressure3.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{30, 50}, {30, 70}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe4.port_b, pressure4.port) annotation(
    Line(points = {{60, 50}, {60, 70}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(pipe4.port_b, valveLinear.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{60, 50}, {60, 10}}, color = {0, 127, 255}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(ramp.y, valveLinear.opening) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-25, 0}, {52, 0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}, thickness = 0.5));
connect(valveLinear.port_b, pipe41.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{60, -10}, {60, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
connect(pipe41.port_b, Outlet.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{40, -50}, {0, -50}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    Diagram);end WaterHammer;

